# Execute dynamic SQL query in Redshift and return a table of results

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to be able to compose and execute a complex SQL `SELECT` statement against a Redshift database that changes depending on the values of various input parameters. The underlying drive here is that I have many different consumers in different programming languages all executing similar - but not identical - SQL queries and I don't want to create a bunch of client libraries to compose SQL statements or have dozens of similar `VIEW`s in my database - what I'd really like is for the client to be able to just call a function on the database server, pass in some input parameters and have it return a table of results for the composed SQL query.

It seems like this is possible for `INSERT` / `UPDATE` statements and for `SELECT` statements if you use cursors - which I don't want to do because my queries will return millions of rows for use in a Pandas dataframe. Is there any way to achieve what I'm aiming for here or is it beyond the capabilities of Redshift? A simplified example would look something like the following (non-working) code:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure(IN region_id VARCHAR) AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE region_id = ''' || region_id || ''';';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note: I should also mention that I know it's possible to create a temporary table in the stored procedure and return it's name  as an `OUT` parameter. I don't want to use this approach - consumption needs to be efficient and simple at the point of use, so I don't want consumers to need to call a procedure, capture output and then call a separate SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this cannot be done this way.  A stored procedure can only return a value, not multiple rows of data.

The way to do this is with a cursor which you have excluded for reasons not clearly stated.  A cursor is a "weigh station" on the normal path for returning data from a SELECT so there is no downside to using this for large return sets.  Is the concern that 2 SQL statements need to be issued - call and fetch?  Are you thinking you need to loop through the cursor to present the results? Why exactly is a cursor not a viable option?

PS. For really large datasets where performance is a concern you should look into UNLOAD and not returning data through the JDBC connection.  The parallel network connections, more streamlined data encoding, and reduced leader-node demands often result in significantly faster data movement.  As the amount of data gets large this upside will become very valuable especially if parallel reading is used on the consuming toolset.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply - I had read that using cursors is a bad idea if you have large datasets to return due to some kind of performance consideration but I hadn't really looked into it any more than that. I'll experiment with a cursor-based implementation and test for myself whether it actually is performant.

Comment: Essentially the requirement here is to load something like 10 million rows of data that result from a SELECT query into a Pandas dataframe in Python code, but I need to compose the SQL for that select query dynamically. I'll do some reading on UNLOAD and get back to you - thanks :)

Comment: So a cursor is just the Redshift leader node storing the results of the query for later access.  In a simple select Redshift needs to store the result on the leader node as the data flows to the client as this network connection is generally much slower than the cluster network.  In both cases it can have performance implications to generate an extremely large result set.  This can be compounded if you don't clean up your cursors quickly.  There are also upsides to cursors - if you want to abort the transfer of data you can just close the cursor.  A regular query needs to send it all out.

Comment: Is 10M rows too much to push through the leader node?  That depends on how big of a node type you are using and how many GBs of data this is (memory allocation).  But almost certainly this is not the fastest way to get the data from Redshift into your dataframe.  Parallel movement out of Redshift (UNLOAD) and parallel loading of you dataframe would be faster.  This will take a bit of coding and your benefit will be dependent on your exact circumstances.